# Implementing Guice on existing project

Tags: java, guice

I'm currently trying to implement Guice in my resteasy solution.
After 8 months using static method... I had to change in order to implement correct unit-test.
I've successfully bootstrapped a short piece of code working. And I quite understood the DI process.

I'm looking further to implement by business logic, but I'm stuck and I don't know how to realize this with Guice.

My App have an Singleton name Metamodel for the example build by Guice and containing a map of Element

There is my Metamodel

```
@Singleton
public class MetamodelImpl implements Metamodel{
    Map<String, Element> elements;

    public MetamodelImpl(){
        // load data from XML files in order to create my Elements
        // using new Element1() etc... function of the type.
    }

    public Element getElement(String name){
        return elements.get(name);
    }
}
```

Then, Here is my Element abstract class, Element can contains other elements, The purpose is to call generateResult in order to generate a RestWrapper (json result, but we don't carre).

```
public abstract class Element{
    List<Element> elements;

    public RestWrapper generateResult(Context context){
        RestWrapper restWrapper = new RestWrapper();

        for (Element element : elements) {
            restWrapper.add(element.generateResult(context));
        }

        return restWrapper;
    }
}
```

There is an example of implementation.

```
public class Element1{
    public RestWrapper generateResult(Context context){

        RestWrapper restWrapper = super.generateResult(context);

        // Add some custom logic using services
        // old code with static use
        Object object = ServiceExample.getResult(property, context);

        // Wanted, by injecting the service, but I can't inject service on element that I create...

        Object object = serviceExampleImpl.getResult(property);
    }
}
```

Context is a Guice object containing my current user and some other stuff. My problem, as you may see is on the generateResult method of an element, I have to call some services that are now Guice Implemented. For example :

```
public class ServiceExampleImpl implements ServiceExample{
    @Inject
    Context context;

    public Object getResult(String property){
        return ...
    }
}
```

How could I do ? How to construct the Element with Guice ? and having the context dynamic ...

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is that you want to do. Is the question just about how you can inject the correct Context object into your ServiceExampleImpl? And why do you not want to pass the Context as a parameter?

Comment: My question is how to have ServiceExample instance on element without passing it in function param (I can't instanciate it in the Element)

Comment: "but I can't inject service on element that I create" probably means that you're using the wrong abstractions. You should be able to inject the context & service into a factory that can then create objects. DI is just used to solve dependencies between components, so that those components can then use each other without knowing the others details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need.

```
@Singleton
public class MetamodelImpl implements Metamodel{
    Map<String, Element> elements;

    @Inject
    public MetamodelImpl(Injector injector){
        Element element = new Element1("Initialize-Me");
        injector.injectMembers(element);
        elements = new HashMap<String, Element>();
        elements.put("Initialize-Me", element);
    }

    public Element getElement(String name){
        return elements.get(name);
    }
}

public class Element1 extends Element {
    @Inject
    private ServiceExample serviceExampleImpl;

    private final String property;

    public Element1(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
    @Override
    public RestWrapper generateResult(Context context){

        RestWrapper restWrapper = super.generateResult(context);

        // Wanted, by injecting the service, but I can't inject service on element that I create...

        Object object = serviceExampleImpl.getResult(property);
        //do something with object

        return restWrapper;
    }
}
```

You initialize your MetamodelImpl and create all of your elements with "new" using the constructors that you need. MetamodelImpl gets a single dependency, the Guice injector injected into the constructor. Once you have created your element with "new" then you call them method injector.injectMembers(...), passing your newly created element as the parameter. This will cause Guice to set the member

```
private ServiceExample serviceExampleImpl;
```

because it is now annotated with @Inject. This means that once you are inside of the generateResult method, the service is now properly set, and can be used.

**Edited - Additional Information about @Assisted inject**

Assisted inject allows you to mix creation of a component, where some values are injected and others are known only at runtime. To use it, you need to create an unimplemented factory interface, which has one method: "create", whose return type is the type that you want to inject with mixed components (some injected, some specified by you at runtime) and whose parameters are exactly the dependencies that are annotated with @Assisted. In my example below, IElement1Factory is this unimplemented interface. Element1 has only 1 parameter that is annotated with @Assisted and so the method in the factory has only 1 parameter. One of the advantages to using assisted-inject is that the component that you create can be intercepted, should you need it to be. Using setter or field injection on an object that you create with "new" does not get subclassed or proxied for interception. When you create it with guice assisted-inject, guice will sub-class it, wrapping the appropriate interceptors, should you need them.

To use assisted inject, you need the following jar. Here is the maven dependency. My code tested with version 4.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In one of your Guice modules, I added the following binding-rule.

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(IElement1Factory.class));
```

together with the interface:

```
public interface IElement1Factory {
    Element1 create(String property);
}
```

Now, my MetamodelImpl looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MetamodelImpl implements Metamodel{
    Map<String, Element> elements;

    @Inject
    public MetamodelImpl(IElement1Factory element1Factory){
        Element element = element1Factory.create("Initialize-Me");
        elements = new HashMap<String, Element>();
        elements.put("Initialize-Me", element);
    }

    public Element getElement(String name){
        return elements.get(name);
    }
}
```

And a Main-method that calls it:

```
public static void main(String ... params) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(IElement1Factory.class));
        }
    });

    MetamodelImpl model = injector.getInstance(MetamodelImpl.class);
    Element element = model.getElement("Initialize-Me");
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Produces the output:

```
stackoverflow.guice.Element1@487a1576
```

Comment: A couple of other things to consider... 1) You could reduce the visibility of the service to default, allowing you to set a mock in a test. 2) You could use setter-injection. 3) instead of creating with "new" you could use assisted-inject

Comment: Can you tell more about assited-inject ?